# How to extract a substring from a given text using NLP?

Tags: regex, python-3.x, machine-learning, nlp

I am trying to extract the substring from a text that does not add any value to the answer. I tried it with n-grams but not getting satisfying results.

I am trying to find the similarity between two text using google universal sentence encoder. I observed that If I clean the text before passing it to the encoder I get better results. I want to extract the text that is repeating from the question as it does not add any value to the answer.

```
def extract_answer(question,answer):
   << some code goes here >>
   return extracted_text

Question = "Why is the plasma membrane called a selectively permeable membrane?"

Answer = "The cell membrane or the plasma membrane is known as a selectively permeable membrane because it regulates the movement of substances in and out of the cell. This means that the plasma membrane allows the entry of only some substances and prevents the movement of some other materials."

extracted_answer = extract_answer(Question,Answer)

print(extracted_answer) 



Sample 1
---------

Input
-------
Question: Why is the plasma membrane called a selectively permeable membrane?
Answer: The cell membrane or the plasma membrane is known as a selectively permeable membrane because it regulates the movement of substances in and out of the cell. This means that the plasma membrane allows the entry of only some substances and prevents the movement of some other materials.

Expected Output
---------------

Output: it regulates the movement of substances in and out of the cell. This means that the plasma membrane allows the entry of only some substances and prevents the movement of some other materials.


Sample 2
----------  

Input
-------
Question: Why is the diver able to cross the river?
Answer: The swimmer is able to cross the river because the particles of matter have space between them. 

Expected Output
---------------

Output: particles of matter have space between them.
```

Answer (score 0):

**General case (questions and answers without patterns):**

Your question is somehow contained in the area of Question Answering. Many researches today uses techinques to extract answers from documents, which might be what you're looking for.

The state of the art researches in this area can be found in ACL (Association for Computer Linguistics): https://aclweb.org/aclwiki/Question_Answering_(State_of_the_art)

That's the case for general text, without patterns.

**Direct questions and answers (follows a pattern):**

However, if your data follows a pattern like "What is x? -> X is blablabla", you can use a set of possible attempts, like the one I propose below (I've used Spacy, but the logic is similar for Google NLP):

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en')

#You can use Machine Learning to find question types better than manual description!
question_type =  {"why":"reason", "what":"factoid", "how":"quantity"}
explanation_words = {"reason":["because"], "factoid":["is", "are"], "quantity":["is", "are"]}

questions = ['Why is the plasma membrane called a selectively permeable membrane?', 'What is a car?', 'How many wheels are there in a car?']
answers = ['The cell membrane or the plasma membrane is known as a selectively permeable membrane because it regulates the movement of substances in and out of the cell. This means that the plasma membrane allows the entry of only some substances and prevents the movement of some other materials.',
          'A car is a vehicle used for human or object transportation.',
          'There are usually 4 wheels in a common car.']

for idx, qa in enumerate(questions):
    doc = nlp(qa)
    q_type = ""
    for token in doc:
        if token.pos_ in ["ADV", "PRON"]:
            q_type = question_type[token.text.lower()]
            break
    answer_doc = nlp(answers[idx])
    answer_start_pos = -1
    for token in answer_doc:
        if token.text in explanation_words[q_type]:
            answer_start_pos = token.idx
            break
    print("\nQuestion: ",qa,"\nAnswer:"," ".join([token.text for token in answer_doc if token.idx > answer_start_pos]))
```

Results:

> Question:  Why is the plasma membrane called a selectively permeable
>   membrane?
>   Answer: it regulates the movement of substances in and out
>   of the cell . This means that the plasma membrane allows the entry of
>   only some substances and prevents the movement of some other materials
>   .
>
> Question:  What is a car?
>   Answer: a vehicle used for human or object
>   transportation .
>
> Question:  How many wheels are there in a car?
>   Answer: usually 4
>   wheels in a common car .

Up to you to check all question types and prettify the results.